# How to use result of pattern matching in R

Tags: r, regex

I have a dataframe with string values

```
id str
a  1
b  10
c  0
d  102
e  010
```

I need to create a flag such that if there is a 0 in the str, the flag is 1 else, the flag is 0

I'm using the following code :

```
df$flag <-ifelse(grep('0', df$str) == "1", 1, 0)
```

But this returns less rows than the number of total rows in df.

On inspection i found that

```
grep('0', df$str[1]) returns int(0)
```

whereas
    grep('0', df$str[2]) returns 1

Any idea how I could use this

Comment: `as.numeric(grepl("0", df$str))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `grepl` like this

```
df <- read.table(text = "id str
a  1
b  10
c  0
d  102
e  010", header = T)

df$Flag <- ifelse(grepl(0,df$str), 1, 0)

> df
  id str Flag
1  a   1    0
2  b  10    1
3  c   0    1
4  d 102    1
5  e  10    1
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#df$flag <- NULL #unneeded. skip it.
df$flag <- ifelse(grepl('0',df$str), 1, 0)
```

You need `grepl` instead of `grep`

Comment: @RonakShah ah you're absolutely right. I am used to initialized another column with NA actually before filling it with ifelse vectorized statement.

Comment: this is known as `JAVA` hangover

Comment: @Hardikgupta would like to know what is `JAVA hangover`?

Comment: nothing against the language (I love it) - In Java we need to initialise every variable before its use, unlike R Python.

Comment: @Hardikgupta haha i see. Sometimes for `NA` value, I encountered error when using `ifelse` statement. Actually that's the reason I have a habit of initializing using `NA`. I am not adept in Java at all :)